# cannot install serialport module nodejs v0.13.0-pre

Tags: node.js, serial-port, node-serialport

I'm trying to use the SerialPort module for serial communication between my udoo and the built in arduino.

The problem is that the the module doesn't install. I wanted to upload the photo with the error but I couldn't because I do not have not enough reputation. But I did upload the photo to my Dropbox and this is the link 
[Error Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ugd2324fgsjnygw/AAA3FBDvOMWYtDn1sLWrW-nHa?dl=0)
I've already check in my other udoo with nodejs version v0.12.0 and another one with v.0.10.35. And is not working, the mayor common problem is related to

`child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.`

Comment: Please place the error message in your actual question. Linking to an image is not useful and makes it much harder to read the question.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `0.13.0-pre` in this project? It is brand new and unstable.

Comment: It was the default version when I installed, and also when I tried to upload the picture said that I'm not as popular as needed, I mean not enough reputation.

Comment: Sorry, I mean you can just paste the text from the error into your question body. Pictures in general are a bad idea for anything other than actual images. How did you install node? I'm very surprised that would be default unless there is a mistake in the installer. As for your edit, it can't be the same error, because the error explicitly mentions "-pre", unless your downgrade failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is *fairly* clear: `Error: "pre" versions of node cannot be installed`. Install a released version of node (e.g. node v0.12) instead and *then* `npm install serialport`.

Comment: And how do a change my current Version to another ?